# What causes leftover XML to exist in files when a component is deleted via the UI?

Tags: apex, deployment, page-layout, xml, deployment-api

I've had interesting situation come up today when doing a metadata validation on a very large package. An error was occurring on a Page Layout where it was expecting that a QuickAction should also be in the package.xml.

Upon investigation I found that the QuickAction did not exist and it had been deleted by an Admin via the UI.

I did retrieve on the metadata for that particular Page Layout and found that the XML still contained an element (example below) for the QuickAction. Deleting this and deploying the file resolved the error.

```
<platformActionListItems>
    <actionName>myQuickAction</actionName>
    <actionType>QuickAction</actionType>
    <sortOrder>2</sortOrder>
</platformActionListItems>
```

I'm looking to have a few things answered:

1. What causes this to happen?
2. Is there a name for this occurrence?
3. Is this prevalent on one type of metadata over another? I have had this happen previously on FlexiPages and chalked it up to a Lightning quirk but it seems to be larger than that.